# Multivariable function: min,max and saddle points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, graphing-functions

Say you are given $f(x,y)$ and you are told to sketch the curve that satisfies the equation $f(x,y)= 0$. My approach at this is to take the partials of my $f(x,y)$, find the critical points, then solve for the $D$ of the function to tell whether the points are min,max or saddle.

I solved a certain problem such that I found saddle point at $(1,3)$. Is this correct? If so how should I go about graphing the curve?

Thanks, any insight will help.

Comment: *What* is correct? You mentioned the problem of sketching a level curve of a function, then you talk about the points  at which the function has a local maximum, or a local minimum, or it is a saddle point, and then you ask “how should I go about graphing the curve?” What is in fact your question?

Comment: My question is should I be graping a saddle at the point (1,3)

Comment: I cannot imagine any use whatsoever for the fact that your function has a saddle point at $(1,3)$ if your goal is to sketch the curve $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: To graph $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, do you worry about the max, min and saddle points of $z = x^2 + y^2 - 1$?